# web apps-script changes not showing on sites page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a google sites page which is produced and controlled by an apps-script published as a web app.  In the past this worked great.  I could make changes in the script, refresh the page and my changes would be reflected instantly. Since the page and script was put into production, I decided to make a copy of the page and script in order to work on a new design.

My connection between page and script appears to have been lost.  I tried deleting the apps-script gadget in the page edit mode and re-insert the new apps-script copy.  However, the copy didn't show up in the list of available apps-scripts.  I went back to the script's publish feature and grabbed the URL.  I did the Insert > "Apps Script" command again and, this time, entered the script URL.

That did seem to give me a new connection.  However, when I make any changes to the script, they are not reflected on the page.  Very frustrating.

I didn't paste any code here because this doesn't appear to be a code issue. Plus, the code has not changed substantially from works currently in the production copy.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what steps you have actually performed, and to what end. If you copy a page that embeds a link, that the link will not be changed just by copying the page - you have to embed the link to the new script's webapp. It also sounds like you have not embedded the "developer preview" version of the webapp link. If you embed the standard `../exec` link, you must Deploy a new version of the app for changes to propagate. If this is not the situation, you need to edit your question to be much more specific.

Comment: I apologize if my comments were not specific enough.  Here's a breakdown of the steps I took:

Comment: 1) From the original page, clicked the More Actions (gear icon) menu and selected Copy Page.
2) Named the page and clicked the red Copy button.
3) In the new copy, deleted the Apps Script Gadget (didn't want to edit the production of the script).
4) From the More Actions menu, selected Manage Site, clicked on Apps Script, clicked Add New Script... (continued in next comment)

Comment: 5) Copied/pasted all code from the original script, saved, clicked the Publish menu item, clicked New version and completed the publish process.  Closed the script browser tab.
6) Noticed, on the Manage page > Apps Script page, with the list of all apps scripts, my new one wasn't showing in the list.  Instead there were the thin gray lines that separate each list item, but where the name of the script should be there was a blank.  I tried the whole process again--adding a new script--but got the same results.  I noticed the count, at the upper right corner of the list showed the

Comment: new count--with the added scripts counted--however the displayed list only showed eight named scripts.  The count said there were 15 (I had added a few times).
6) I went back to the page to insert the new script to see if maybe the script would show up in the insert script dialog.  In Edit mode, clicked Insert > Apps Script.  The original eight showed in the dialog, with blank spaces in various places in the list, apparently where the new ones were added but not showing their names.

Comment: This seems like a bug in the G Suite Sites system.  I reached out to the help resource.  The person in the chat session referred my case to the "Sites team" and said they would get back to me, via email, within eight hours.  That was at 11:30 am, Friday, March 16th.  It's now 2:40 pm Saturday, the 17th and I've heard from no one.

Comment: As described in my initial question, I went back over the whole process again, but this time grabbed the URL in the Publish process and kept the new script browser tab open.  Back on the page, in the Insert Apps Script dialog, pasted the URL in the textbox below the list of scripts, saved, etc.  The page loaded with the basic functionality of the script.  I thought I had achieved success, until I made a change to the script and it wasn't reflected in the page.